# Shortening Python list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am someone coming from a JavaScript background.

Is there a cleaner, more pythonic method to writing the following below while keeping it within an 80 char limit to follow the standard flake8 style guide rules?

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) if ('file' in entry and entry['file'] == name) or ('guide_directory' in entry and entry['guide_directory'] == name)), None)
```

Comment: There are multiple acceptable methods, the provided answer is one of them, but you can follow one of the 4-space indent (the hanging indent) as described by [pep8.org](https://pep8.org/#code-lay-out).

Comment: Assuming `entry` is a `dict` and `name` can't be `None` the `'file' in entry and entry['file'] == name` can be replaced by `entry.get('file') == name` and similar for the next part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indent list comprehensions as you like since they are surrounded by brackets or parents. Just an example

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
            if ('file' in entry and entry['file'] == name) or 
               ('guide_directory' in entry and 
                entry['guide_directory'] == name)),
         None)
```

There is some possible refactoring to

```
('file' in entry and entry['file'] == name)`
```

can be

```
entry.get('file') == name
```

The same with `('guide_directory' in entry and entry['guide_directory'] == name)`

I guess the above is valid for your case too,

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
            if name and name in (entry.get('file'), entry.get('guide_directory')),
         None)
```

If you're sure that name is not None, this is even shorter

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
            if name in (entry.get('file'), entry.get('guide_directory')),
         None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more concise version:

```
next(
   (i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) if name in {
             entry.get('file'),
            entry.get('guide_directory')}),
   None)
```

Comment: Why not use string equality and `or` instead of the 2-element sets you're creating and then searching using `in`?

Comment: @SaswatPadhi Because I want OP to tun into a performance problem and comes back and learns more, I guess :)).

Comment: But OP would run into a problem that wasn't there in the first place. It's like introducing a bug (at least a perf issue) into OP's code ...

Comment: @SaswatPadhi How do you know that? And how do you know this is less efficient than comparing them and/or checking if it contains the key?

Comment: I meant that OP wasn't creating temporary sets for _each_ entry. OP was using string equality checks and `or`

Comment: @SaswatPadhi That's exactly right, thanks for the noes tho, I hope OP sees the comments I think that'd be enough.

Comment: The set approach leads to half the instructions than the or one, and seems to run faster https://gist.github.com/dhilst/2e6f02f4a0eff26581f1a6919330ae35

Comment: @geckos: It's actually not -- it's more than 2x slower. Your script doesn't test the right behavior. Your set is a constant, that's why it _appears_ fast. In Kasrâmvd's code it's not a constant set, but the elements are created by function calls.

Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/SaswatPadhi/eef95e7deb01f54725e013f6cd09aa19

Comment: Good catch! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get` for `dict`s instead of checking if the key is `in` the `dict`.

```py
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
            if entry.get('file') == name or 
               entry.get('guide_directory') == name),
         None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `name` can’t be `None`, you can use `dict.get`:

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) if entry.get('file') == name or entry.get('guide_directory') == name), None)
```

Then `in`:

```
i = next((i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) if name in (entry.get('file'), entry.get('guide_directory')), None)
```

Then make a function:

```
def find_index(iterable, predicate):
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(iterable) if predicate(x)), None)


i = find_index(toc[key], lambda entry:
        name in (entry.get('file'), entry.get('guide_directory')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use explicit line continuations unless the line will be a valid statement on its own. For that reason you can wrap results in parenthesis to continue the statement. This is commonly used for long strings.

e.g.

```
foobar = "This is a really really long string that could not normally doesnt look very good because its too long for a simple line of code"

foobar = (
    "This is a really really long string "
    "that could not normally doesnt look "
    "very good because its too long for a "
    "simple line of code"
)
```

Here's the same statement broken up (also you can use `get` to safely check dictionaries without doing the key check):

```
i = next(
    (
        i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
        if (
            entry.get('file') == name 
            or entry.get('guide_directory') == name
        )
    ),
    None,
)
```

Another style point is to break up complex logic into its own method. This allows you to both unit test the internal component, and possible reuse later. Here's how I'd go about writing that statement:

```
def valid_entry(name: str, entry: Dict[str, Any]) -> bool:
    return (
       entry.get('file') == name 
       or entry.get('guide_directory') == name
    )

generator = (
    i for i, entry in enumerate(toc[key]) 
    if valid_entry(name, entry)
)
i = next(generator, None)
```